# epoll message server

Tags: c, epoll

I want to create a message server using epoll. Several devices will connect to the server and exchange simple text messages. I don't have that much experience with this and I will be very appreciated if you guys can provide me any references or tutorials related to this.

I would like to work with C. Thanks in advance.

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you start by taking a look [here](http://banu.com/2011/06/how-to-use-epoll-complete-example/), and keeping [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) close as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be quicker to use an existing message queue solution.  [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) is such a solution and it uses epoll under the hood.  It has [C bindings](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ac) and allows you to work at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [epoll level triggered code](https://github.com/felipecruz/rio/blob/master/src/network.c#L296) and check how it works..